# Why are the LED lights in my ceiling fan suddenly dim?

Tags: ceiling-fan, led

Installed ceiling fan with LED lights. Circuit has three way switches no dimmers. Lights worked fine for a 1-1/2 months, but then turned on one morning and lights are dim. Fan has a remote to turn on and off.

Comment: Does the fan remote also control the lights? Are you sure they weren't always dim when off?

Comment: There is not enough information provided for the community to help you.

Comment: On the fans with remotes I have seen, the remote also controls the lights. And usually if you hold the on/off button for lights (or some similar action), it will dim the lights. So try holding the button on the remote if there is one and see if you can bring the lights back to how you want them.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the driver for the LED has started to fail, I have seen this a few times , I would check to see if it is under warranty and exchange it.